# Bold face title and different font sizes in the same title

Tags: fontsize, titles, bold

How could I make every character bold in the title? Also, is it possible to make "Faculty of Science" smaller size than the University's name at the same time?
I'm new to TeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
  \posttitle{%
    \par\end{center}
    \begin{center}\LARGE#1\end{center}
    \vskip0.5em}%
}

\title{The University of Alberta
\\Faculty of Science}
\subtitle{(Paper Title)}
\author{(Author)}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could change `The University of Alberta` to `\textbf{The University of Alberta}`, and so on. For sizing, try replacing `Faculty of Science` with `{\Large Faculty of Science}`. (Note carefully the positioning of the `{` and `}` characters.)

Comment: @JohnWickerson thx! but it doesn't work. And I want the whole title bold not only "faculty XXX"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
  \posttitle{%
    \par\end{center}
    \begin{center}\LARGE#1\end{center}
    \vskip0.5em}%
}

\title{\textbf{The University of Alberta
\\{\Large Faculty of Science}}}
\subtitle{(Paper Title)}
\author{(Author)}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]